# .NET Core 2.0 Regex Timeout deadlocking

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a .NET Core 2.0 application where I iterate over many files (600,000) of varying sizes (220GB total).

I enumerate them using

```
new DirectoryInfo(TargetPath)
    .EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .GetEnumerator()
```

and iterate over them using

```
Parallel.ForEach(contentList.GetConsumingEnumerable(),
    new ParallelOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2
    },
    file => ...
```

Inside of that, I have a list of regex expressions that I then scan the file with using

```
Parallel.ForEach(_Rules,
    new ParallelOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2
    },
    rule => ...
```

Finally, I get the matches using an **instance** of the Regex class

```
RegEx = new Regex(
    Pattern.ToLowerInvariant(),
    RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Compiled,
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_MaxSearchTime))
```

This instance is shared among all files so I compile it once.  There are 175 patterns that are applied to the files.

At random (ish) spots, the application deadlocks and is completely unresponsive.  No amount of try/catch stops this from happening.  If I take the exact same code and compile it for .NET Framework 4.6 it works without any problems.

I've tried LOTS of things and my current test which seems to work (but I am very wary!) is to NOT use an INSTANCE, but instead to call the STATIC `Regex.Matches` method every time.  I can't tell how much of a hit I am taking on performance, but at least I am not getting deadlocks.

I could use some insight or at least serve as a cautionary tale.

**Update:**
I get the file list like this:

```
private void GetFiles(string TargetPath, BlockingCollection<FileInfo> ContentCollector)
    {
        List<FileInfo> results = new List<FileInfo>();
        IEnumerator<FileInfo> fileEnum = null;
        FileInfo file = null;
        fileEnum = new DirectoryInfo(TargetPath).EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).GetEnumerator();
        while (fileEnum.MoveNext())
        {
            try
            {
                file = fileEnum.Current;
                //Skip long file names to mimic .Net Framework deficiencies
                if (file.FullName.Length > 256) continue;
                ContentCollector.Add(file);
            }
            catch { }
        }
        ContentCollector.CompleteAdding();
    }
```

Inside my Rule class, here are the relevant methods:

```
_RegEx = new Regex(Pattern.ToLowerInvariant(), RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Compiled, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_MaxSearchTime));
...
    public MatchCollection Matches(string Input) { try { return _RegEx.Matches(Input); } catch { return null; } }
    public MatchCollection Matches2(string Input) { try { return Regex.Matches(Input, Pattern.ToLowerInvariant(), RegexOptions.Multiline, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_MaxSearchTime)); } catch { return null; } }
```

Then, here is the matching code:

```
    public List<SearchResult> GetMatches(string TargetPath)
    {
        //Set up the concurrent containers
        ConcurrentBag<SearchResult> results = new ConcurrentBag<SearchResult>();
        BlockingCollection<FileInfo> contentList = new BlockingCollection<FileInfo>();

        //Start getting the file list
        Task collector = Task.Run(() => { GetFiles(TargetPath, contentList); });
        int cnt = 0;
        //Start processing the files.
        Task matcher = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //Process each file making it as parallel as possible                
            Parallel.ForEach(contentList.GetConsumingEnumerable(), new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2 }, file =>
            {
                //Read in the whole file and make it lowercase
                //This makes it so the Regex engine does not have
                //to do it for each 175 patterns!
                StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(file.FullName));
                string inputString = stream.ReadToEnd();
                stream.Close();
                string inputStringLC = inputString.ToLowerInvariant();

                //Run through all the patterns as parallel as possible
                Parallel.ForEach(_Rules, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2 }, rule =>
                {
                    MatchCollection matches = null;
                    int matchCount = 0;
                    Stopwatch ruleTimer = Stopwatch.StartNew();

                    //Run the match for the rule and then get our count (does the actual match iteration)
                    try
                    {
                        //This does not work - Causes Deadlocks:
                        //matches = rule.Matches(inputStringLC);

                        //This works - No Deadlocks;
                        matches = rule.Matches2(inputStringLC);

                        //Process the regex by calling .Count()
                        if (matches == null) matchCount = 0;
                        else matchCount = matches.Count;
                    }

                    //Catch timeouts
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //Log the error
                        string timeoutMessage = String.Format("****** Regex Timeout: {0} ===> {1} ===> {2}", ruleTimer.Elapsed, rule.Pattern, file.FullName);
                        Console.WriteLine(timeoutMessage);
                        matchCount = 0;
                    }
                    ruleTimer.Stop();

                    if (matchCount > 0)
                    {
                        cnt++;
                        //Iterate the matches and generate our match records
                        foreach (Match match in matches)
                        {
                            //Fill my result object
                            //...

                            //Add the result to the collection
                            results.Add(result);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        //Wait until all are done.
        Task.WaitAll(collector, matcher);

        Console.WriteLine("Found {0:n0} files with {1:n0} matches", cnt, results.Count);


        return results.ToList();
    }
```

**Update 2**
The test I was running did not deadlock, but when it got close to the end, it seemed to stall, but I could still break into the process with VS.  I then realized I didn't have the Timeout set on my test whereas I did in the code I posted (`rule.Matches` and `rule.Matches2`).  **WITH** the timeout, it deadlocks.  **WITHOUT** the timeout, it does not.  Both still work in .Net Framework 4.6.  I need the timeout on the regex because there are some large files that some of the patterns stall out on.

**Update 3:**
I've been playing with timeout values and it seems to be some combination of threads running, exceptions from timeouts, and the timeout value that causes the Regex engine to deadlock.  I can't pin it down exactly, but a timeout >= 5 minutes seems to help.  As a temporary fix, I may set the value to 10 minutes, but this is not a permanent fix!

Comment: can you provide a minimum example? chances are that there might be some conflict or hidden event in your code or a 3rd party lib that's causing it

Comment: Can you post a stacktrace where it hangs? I think this is more related that the enumerator is not thread safe.

Comment: I cannot post a stack trace since the process is completely deadlocked.  I can't even break in w/ Visual Studio.  Any attempt to pause or introduce a breakpoint causes VS to freeze until I kill the app and then it says "Couldn't set the breakpoint!"

Comment: From [C# 7.0 in a Nutshell](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920083634.do): *Parallel.For and Parallel.ForEach usually work best on outer rather than inner loops. This is because with the former, you’re offering larger chunks of work to parallelize, diluting the management overhead. Parallelizing both inner and outer loops is usually unnecessary.* This is for `Parallel.ForEach` in `Parallel.ForEach` in `GetMatches`.

Comment: I took out BOTH Parallel.Foreach as a test and instead populated arrays of tasks for outside and inside loops.  I saw less Regex timeouts and one particular sample set completed correctly and was even a bit faster, but when running the full data set, it still deadlocked as before.

Comment: Are you sure it's *deadlock*ing? Looks like it may just be taking a long time. Anyway, a lot of the code here can be tidied up. You don't need `BlockingCollection`, for example. Simply have `GetFiles` return an `IEnumerable` and `yield return` each file. This lets you get rid of the tasks entirely. You don't need the inner `Parallel.ForEach` (just use a regular `foreach`), and you can utilize [thread-local variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-parallel-foreach-loop-with-thread-local-variables) instead of `results`.

Comment: At the very least, doing the above will allow you to remove external variables which may contribute to the deadlocking behavior.

Comment: If you can still repro this -- you can get a view of the stacks by externally triggering a dump of the process and then opening the dump in a debugger. For instance, try using [perfview](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/highcpucapture/2017/07/16/perfview-command-for-capturing-automated-high-cpu-dumps/).

Answer (score 1):

If I should guess, I would blame Regex

- `RegexOptions.Compiled` is not implemented in .NET Core 2.0 ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51090297/2361))
- Some of your 175 patterns may be [slightly evil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS#Malicious_regexes)

This may lead to significant performance difference between .NET Framework 4.6 and .NET Core 2.0 which may result in unresponsive application.