# .NET Core 2.1 - Regex in loop 200x slower than 2.0 (3x in simple benchmark)

Tags: c#, regex, .net-core

I have the following regex:

```
    var regex = new Regex(
        @"^ActiveMQ[\d\.-]*$",
        RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
```

It runs over ~1000 strings (`IsMatch` call). In .NET Core 2.0 it takes around `10ms`. After migrating to .NET Core 2.1 it takes over `2 seconds` on the same data.

Any idea what's going on? Any behavior changes in 2.1?

======================

**Update: BenchmarkDotNet**

Reproducible 3x drop (just run, change `netcoreapp2.1` to `netcoreapp2.0` in `csproj` file, run again).
https://github.com/ptupitsyn/netcore2.1-regex-perf/tree/master/src

- Simplifying actual application as much as possible has reduced the drop, but it 
  is still very much visible.
- Flipping the nested loops in `GetPackageInfos2` reduces the perf drop to only `25%`, but it is still there. Changing this in real-world code is not trivial and I would like to avoid this kind of refactoring.
- There are multiple RegEx executed in a loop, and I could not reproduce the drop with only one RegEx

**Update 2**

Removing `RegexOptions.Compiled` solves the problem!

Comment: How are you testing this?

Comment: I'm using a profiler on some real-world app. I'm going to create a simple reproducer as well. @CamiloTerevinto

Comment: How long are these strings?

Comment: Using [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) to get a reproducible benchmark would help. Compare GC and IL results to see if the problem is due to different `Regex` code or a JIT issue. (A `Regex` issue would be [CoreFX](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues), a JIT issue would be [CoreCLR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues).)

Comment: I was able to repro your findings.  One wouldn't expect compiled regexs to *match* slower in 2.1, and thus I think you've found a bug.  [Please report it on GitHub here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues).  Thanks.

Comment: Reported: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/30131

Comment: If you've found the answer - you should post the answer! Posting the answer to your own question seems counter -intuitive but it greatly increases the value of this post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`RegexOptions.Compiled` is **not implemented** in .NET Core 2.0, but **is implemented** in .NET Core 2.1.

Compilation involves initial overhead, and for certain usage patterns this overhead outweighs the gains of compiled regex.

My case is somewhat complex, and it seems like there might be a bug in .NET, because even with a proper benchmark (with warm-up), `Compiled` mode is slower. See details in Corefx issue: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/30131

Comment: As additional tip: use compiled, but compile once - into a static instance.

Comment: @TomTom This is a good tip, but as I explained, it does not help in my case. See reproducer in https://github.com/ptupitsyn/netcore2.1-regex-perf/tree/master/src